# Flutter PageView Scroll but only for widgets and not entire pages

Tags: flutter, dart, scrollview, flutter-pageview, tiktok

Today I have a question, not providing any code.
I would like to create  a tiktok like experience for scrolling through my appfeed in flutter. However I don't want to scroll an entire page when I swipe, only to the next widget in the ListView/PageView. I am only able to swipe an entire page with pageview and I'm only able to scroll normally on Listview. Is there any solution for my request? I hope I clarified enough what I mean. Instagram offers such an experience on its Search. Is there any possibility how one could realize something like that?
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Use ListView.builder inside the Container with the 500px height and the  ListView.builder will have the children posts thus you stay inside the same feed with the ability to swipe thru posts vertically or horizontally.

Check the following link for a tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=baA_J5tUtEU

You can change the scrolling by setting scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal or Axis.vertical inside the ListView.buidler

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thank you but I'm sorry but thats not what I was looking for. Yes I want something like a listview but with  a tiktok like experience and that is missing in your example on a swipe i dont want a simple scroll instead i want a a jump to the next item inside the feed.

Comment: check this out https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wnTYKJEJ7f4

Answer (score 0):

So what you want to do is to use a Stack widget and then put the pageview, just as you would if you were creating an onboarding screen with flutter, something like this

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class OnBoarding extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _OnBoardingState createState() => _OnBoardingState();
}

class _OnBoardingState extends State<OnBoarding> {
  PageController? controller;
  int currentIndex = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    controller = PageController();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller!.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          PageView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            onPageChanged: onchahged,
            controller: controller,
            children: [
              Container(
                child: Image.network(
                  'https://picsum.photos/200/300',
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                child: Image.network(
                  'https://picsum.photos/200/300',
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                child: Image.network(
                  'https://picsum.photos/200/300',
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Positioned(
            bottom: 30,
            right: 10,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Icon(
                  Icons.ac_unit,
                  size: 30,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
                Icon(
                  Icons.image,
                  size: 30,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
                Icon(
                  Icons.person,
                  size: 30,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
                Icon(
                  Icons.person_add,
                  size: 30,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  onchahged(int index) {
    setState(() {
      currentIndex = index;
    });
  }
}
```

Here's what it looks like
[image]

Comment: Thank you, but I think I haven't been clear enough. 
Unfortunately this is not what I was looking for. For example, if the image in your answer is only 500px high and you would swipe, you would also get to a new screen. However, I am looking for a kind of page view for widgets that are smaller than the entire screen height. If you swipe, you should stay in the feed, but instead of scrolling smoothly like on a scrollview, you should jump to the next post like in your pageview provided. Kind od a mix between Listview and PageView

Comment: I don't think I understand what you're asking, hopefully someone else could help you.

Answer (score 0):

For the specific Widget you must to wrap it with a GestureDetector and prevent from the current widget being scrollable.

An example:

```
GestureDetector(
   onHorizontalDragUpdate: (_) {},
   child: WidgetToNotBeingScrollableInTheHorizontal(),
);
```